# Relationship between connectedness and continuity

Tags: continuity, connectedness

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$.

1. $f$ is continuous,
2. The graph of $f$ if connected in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$

We define "connected" to be cannot be separated by 2 disjoint non-empty open set.

My thinking is that continuous is stronger. Because

$f(x) = sin(1/x)$ when $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$ is connected but not continuous.

How to prove the continuous implies connected?

Comment: Technically speaking a set is connected if it can't be defined as the union of two separated nonempty sets (whereas two sets $A$ and $B$ are separated if $A \cap \overline{B} = \overline{A} \cap B = \emptyset$)

Comment: I think there's more relationship between continuity of $f$ and compactness of it's graph! (no idea why I think so :) )

Comment: aah [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304601/fm-1-to-m-2-is-continuous-iff-its-graph-is-compact) search result supports my idea

Comment: @DanZimm Well, *technically* your definition and the OP's definition are equivalent. =)

Comment: @PeterTamaroff i was saying that more for an idea starter on how to prove what he wanted to prove, otherwise pretty much yes :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right.

a) If $f:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then the graph of $f$ is path connected, whence connected ([see here](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Path-connected_implies_connected), for instance).

**Proof:** if $(x,f(x))$ and $(y,f(y))$ are two points on the graph, then 
$$
t\longmapsto ((1-t)x+ty,f((1-t)x+ty))
$$
is a continuous path connecting them within the graph. QED.

b) Your example is great. This graph is connected and the function is yet discontinuous.

**Note:** I should add that in general, if $f:C\longrightarrow X$ is continuous, and if $C$ is connected, then the graph of $f$ is connected in $C \times X$ as the continuous image of $C$ under $x\longmapsto (x,f(x))$. This is because continuity preserves connectedness.

Comment: Do you have any other counter examples for b)?

Comment: @JFK Not at the moment, sorry.

Comment: @JFK By [closed graph theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClosedGraphTheorem.html), you need to look for graphs that is open and connected, but $f$ not continuous.

Comment: @mezhang: I cannot find a relation between the link and a discontinuous function with connected graph. the theorem you linked is about linear functions. And I appreciate if you can give me a function with open graph!

Comment: @CutieKrait $T$ is any function, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem). I don't know how to find open graph.

Answer (score 1):

Reminds me of a problem of cutting a pancake of an arbitrary shape in half by a single slice/line. The idea of the solution relies on the Cauchy definition of continuity.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I realize you don't yet have enough reputation, but this is better left as a comment as opposed to being an answer to the OP. Regards

Comment: Is there a way to mark a response as a helpful comment rather than a complete answer? Thank you.

Comment: Not until you have enough reputation