# Let $(X,\tau)$ be compact Hausdorff with $C(X,\Bbb R)$ finite dimensional. Show that $X$ is finite

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

If $(X,\tau)$ is a compact Hausdorff topological space so that $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ is finite dimensional real vector space, would any one help me to show $X$ is finite set? $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ denotes the set of all real valued continuous function on $X$. Only hints are needed.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199279/two-hausdorff-topology-problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume by contradiction that $X$ is infinite. Pick $x_1,..,x_{n+1} \in X$. Pick $U_i$ open sets so that $x_i \in U_i$ and $U_i$ pairwise disjoint.

For each $i$ get some $f_i \in C(X, \mathbb R)$ so that $f(x_i)\neq 0$ and  $supp(f_i) \subset U_i$. Prove that $f_i$ are linearly independent.

**P.S.** Here is a neat overkill solution idea. If $ C(X, \mathbb R)$ is finite dimensional, so is $C(X, \mathbb C)$, and hence its dual: $C(X, \mathbb C)'$. By [Riesz Representation Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem), since $X$ is compact, $C(X, \mathbb C)'$ is just the space of measures on $X$.

The measures $\{ \delta_x \}_{x \in X}$ are linearly independent, and since $C(X, \mathbb C)'$  is finite dimensional, $X$ is finite.